# Is Markov inequality necessary?

Tags: probability-theory

In the proof of Lévy's continuity theorem in Probability Theory by A. Klenke the following inequalities are obtained by using the Markov inequality. Is it necessary? I don't understand how it is used here:

$P([-K,K]) = \int_{[-K,K]} P(dx)
\leq \alpha^{-1} \int_{[-K,K]} h(x/K) P(dx)
\leq \alpha^{-1} \int_{\mathbb{R}} h(x/K) P(dx)$

where $K>0$, $h(x)=1-sin(x)/x$ if $x\neq 0$ and $h(0)=0$ and $\alpha=\inf \{h(x): |x|\geq1\}$.

If I am right the first inequality could be obtained by the fact that $h(x)/\alpha\geq1$ if $|x|\geq1$. Finally, the second follows from the fact that $h\geq0$ and "extending" the integration set does not reduce the value of the integral.

Is my reasoning right? Could you point me how prof. Klenke is using the Markov's inequality?

Thank you.

Comment: If you look at how the Markov inequality is proved, then you see that both statement are simply equivalent. Look at the following proof: $\mathbb E[X] \geq \mathbb E[X | X > a]\cdot \mathbb P[X > a]$. Reformulating this inequality yields Markov's Inequality. That is exactly, what you say!

Comment: How do you introduce the $h$ function which is positive but not monotone increasing? Thank you.

Comment: In general, you can extend Markov inequality to any non-negative function $h$ and any random variable $X$ by the following statement: ${\mathbb P}(h(X)>a)\le a^{-1} {\mathbb E}[h(X)]$. $h(\cdot)$ does not have to be monotone.

Comment: Do you mean that I could define some function, let call it $s$ as in the Wikipedia proof, that is $0$ if $h<a$ and $a$ if $h>a$, to obtain this latter statement, @Stas Volkov? But then, how can I substitute in it $\alpha$ of my OP? Does the fact that "$\alpha$ is the minimum" argument hold again? Thank you.